# Maven 'test' command that only runs the tests that failed

Tags: maven

Is there a way to call the maven 'test' command that only runs the tests that failed the last time it was called?

Comment: I don't think so, since it would require persisting test output and re-loading it. Risky, too, since changing a non-test class to pass a test should run all associated tests anyway, not just the previous failures.

Comment: This sounds like a job for the IDE which is usally supported by Ecilpse, Netbeans or IntelliJ..

Answer (score 5):

Try using the surefire plugin's [runOrder](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder) parameter.  It doesn't look like it has an `${expression}` allowing you to change the property from the command line, so I would roll my own:

```
... POM stuff here....
<properties>
    <!-- plugin's default value for this param -->  
    <surefire.test.runOrder>filesystem</surefire.test.runOrder>
</properties>
....
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <runOrder>${surefire.test.runOrder}</runOrder>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
....
```

Then you may choose the setting you want at the command line:

`mvn -Dsurefire.test.runOrder=failedfirst test` (or `package` or whatever phase you want).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I ran all the tests the first time, they all passed. Then I ran the command you suggested, but in the results, it said it ran all the tests again.

Comment: Try modifying one of the tests that typically run at the end to make it fail.  Then repeat your test.  The one that failed should run first, followed by all the others.  The suggested config doesn't run ONLY failed tests, it runs failed ones first.  Since your test run didn't include failed tests, all were run again.

Comment: I see. But I was specifically looking for a way to *not* run the tests that passed during the last run. Is there a way?

Comment: I suggest experimenting with the other config properties in the surefire plugin.  What you're asking for isn't a common use case.  When a test fails, often changes are required in the code, and we want to make sure those changes don't fix the broken test, but break things somewhere else.  As @khmarbaise points out, if you only want to run individual broken tests, you specify the test on the cmdline, (with `-Dtest`) or use an IDE.